# Error while trying to install ruby gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

while trying to install gem scss-lint , the following error throwed

`gem install scss-lint`

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
>       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

the following screen shot is my gem environment

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#installation use `gem install scss_lint`

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible the naming is wrong? Try using an underscore when installing.

```
gem install scss_lint
```